# Form not submitting programmatically

Tags: html, forms, post

The form [here](http://platform.learning.com/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fInterface%2fStudentSky%2fAssignments.aspx) works fine in the browser, but for some reason I cannot submit it programmatically.

If I do not enter anything in the form in the browser then when I submit I get a 'Log-In Error'. But If I try sending a POST request to the form action url (with and without parameters) the response is the same page. Why is this?

Comment: I shall venture a guess: JavaScript.

Comment: I looked at the page source, JavaScript is not a factor in submission of the form. Plus when I disable JavaScript, the form works fine in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably aren't accounting for all of the `<input />` fields. When serializing the form, I get this list of parameters:

```
__EVENTTARGET=
__EVENTARGUMENT=
__VIEWSTATE=
UserLoginControl%24districtId=
UserLoginControl%24districtName=
UserLoginControl%24UserName=
UserLoginControl%24UserPassword=
UserLoginControl%24district=
districtId=
districtName=
ScreenWidth=
ScreenHeight=
FlashPlayerVersion=
```

Make sure you set *all* of them (or guess and check which ones don't mean anything).